# Stata version of R's Anova Type III?

Tags: r, regression, anova, stata, deviance

I'm trying to perform a type 3 partial deviance analysis of my model parameters in Stata. In R, this would be as simple as "anova(model, type = "III"), but I am not finding an equivalence in Stata. For reference, this is for a Poisson regression model.

Any ideas?